# Getting a python panda data frame's row name as a string

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, row

Having found the maximum value in a panda data frame column, I am just trying to get the equivalent row name as a string.

Here's my code:

```
df[df['ColumnName'] == df['ColumnName'].max()].index
```

Which returns me an answer:

```
Index(['RowName'], dtype='object')
```

How do I just get RowName back?

(stretch question - why does `.idmax()` fry in the formulation `df['Colname'].idmax`?  And, yes, I have tried it as `.idmax()` and also appended it to `df.loc[:,'ColName']` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just use integer indexing:

```
df[df['ColumnName'] == df['ColumnName'].max()].index[0]
```

Here `[0]` extracts the first element. Note your criterion may yield multiple indices.